# Java - sharing static methods across classes

Tags: java, oop

I've got three classes that are meant to simulate mips32 pipeline registers. They all look pretty much like this.

```
class IDEX {
  public static Map<String, Integer> write;
  public static Map<String, Integer> read;

  static {
    Map<String, Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    tempMap.put("incrPC", 0);
    tempMap.put("readReg1Value", 0);
    tempMap.put("readReg2Value", 0);
    tempMap.put("seOffset", 0);
    tempMap.put("writeReg_20_16", 0);
    tempMap.put("writeReg_15_11", 0);
    tempMap.put("function", 0);
    read = new HashMap<String, Integer>(tempMap);
    write = new HashMap<String, Integer>(tempMap);
  }
}
```

I also have some utility methods for copying data from the hashmaps and formatting/printing them.

How can I share these methods across all my register classes? In general, is it possible to share methods between classes that work on their respective static variables?

Comment: I think of this more of a conceptual issue - having mutable public static fields smells like a Java way of simulating global variables, so I would step back and think about the actual use-case here instead of the question where to move what.

Comment: From what I can see, I’d design with instance fields and methods, not static. Wouldn’t it solve more problems that it would create?

Comment: not sure why everything is static, anyways calling a `static` method in a class is like this `MyClassName.methodName()` BUT why don't you put these util methods in a class and let register classes `extends` that class? then you can call it directly inside the register classes, ex in a new method named `copyMap()` or `printFormatted()` ?

Comment: I think @Smutje is on point, I'm basically trying to create global variables.  I'm avoiding creating class instances as much as I can, I'm not a Java programmer so I didn't foresee problems with this (oops). My solution so far has been to make a `RegisterService` class that performs these utility functions on the static members. Still, it seems reasonable that there would be a way to share static methods.